# How can I interpolate time-series data?

Tags: interpolation, time-series

I fetch financial data like this:

```
data = 
  FinancialData["SBUX", "Close", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2013, 8, 1}, "Week"}, "Value"];
```

The above expression will return timeseries formatted data. How would I convert this to a regular list with even spacing (this is very important to me) to make interpolation on this data set work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time series that `FinancialData` creates has the option `TemporalRegularity -> Automatic`. With this option, this series does not interpolate values.

```
data = 
  FinancialData["SBUX", "Close", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2013, 8, 1}, "Week"}, "Value"];
```

Time series that aren't regularly sampled can interpolate values with the option `TemporalRegularity -> True`. To demonstrate, let's use [`TimeSeries`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) to make a list of dates between two of the `data` samples. Change the `data` time series to assume regular time samples with `TemporalRegularity -> True`.

```
 {dt1, dt2} = data["Dates"][[9;;10]];
 dates = DateRange[dt1, dt2];
 ts = TimeSeries[data, TemporalRegularity -> True];
```

The `data` series does not interpolate values.

```
data[dates]
```

> `{$27.43, $27.43, $27.43, $27.43, $27.43, $27.43, $27.43, $29.33}`

With `TemporalRegularity -> True`, the `ts` series linearly interpolates values for dates between samples.

```
ts[dates]
```

> `{$27.43, $27.71, $27.98, $28.25, $28.52, $28.79, $29.06, $29.33}`

---

To get evenly-spaced interpolated values for the entire time series, use the first and last dates of the series for the list of dates. With these new dates, `ts[dates]` gives regular, evenly-spaced values. Here's a plot of the interpolated values.

```
ts = TimeSeries[data, TemporalRegularity -> True];
{dt1, dt2} = ts /@ {"FirstDate", "LastDate"};
dates = DateRange[dt1, dt2];
DateListPlot[Transpose[{dates, ts[dates]}]]
```

[image: interpolated values from time series]

Comment: Thank you. BTW very elegant response. Do you know how to take the dollar values and convert it into a pure numerical list? e.g. {27.43, 27,71, ...}.

Comment: @JonDu I'm happy the answer was helpful... and yes, remove the dollar units from values with [`QuantityMagnitude`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html).

Comment: can I ask what [[9 ;; 10]] means in your code? I understand [[]] is to extract the value but what does [[a;;b]] mean?

Comment: @JonDu `[[a ;; b]]` gives parts *a* through *b* of an expression, for example, `{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}[[2 ;; 4]]` gives `{4, 6, 8}`. See the documentation for [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html). I picked the `[[9 ;; 10]]` samples because they show a clear example of the interpolation.

Comment: Cool! I have another issue that when I try to see output of data[dates] it always shows 8 elements even though I set the dates interval to 3 months. So when I do QuantityMagnitude[data[dates]] there are 8 values. Is there a way to take out all the price data from the interval I defined?

Comment: @JonDu I think you missed  `{dt1, dt2} = ts /@ {"FirstDate", "LastDate"}; dates = DateRange[dt1, dt2]`, then `ts[dates]`, *not* `data[dates]`, gives 210 interpolated values. To get the 31 sample values from `data`, you can use `QuantityMagnitude[data]["Values"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I credited you and I've made a public shared stock price moving average analysis on github. https://github.com/jdou86/StockmovingAvg

Answer (score 1):

Ummm, I'm not sure what do you want. Likely, just use `Normal`:

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, but Normal is a cool function

Answer (score 1):

```
data = FinancialData["SBUX", "Close", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2013, 8, 1}, "Week"}, "Value"]
```

[image]

```
data["Properties"]
```

> ```
> {"DatePath", "Dates", "FinancialProperty", "FirstDate", "FirstTime",
>  "FirstValue", "LastDate", "LastTime", "LastValue", "Path", 
>  "PathComponent", "PathComponents", "PathFunction", "PathLength", 
>  "Times", "ValueDimensions", "Values"}
> ```

You can use the property `"Path"`:

```
data["Path"]
```

[image]